# integrate mesh system in existing wired network

Tags: wired-networking, google-wifi

I have a wired network built around a wifi router. I was wondering how I could integrate a wifi mesh into this configuration.  I need to bring wifi to more rooms in the house and I thought of using a  mesh system instead of a repeater.

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that Nighthawk supports Netgear's version of a mesh network?

Comment: No I don't think it does. That's why I was wondering what my options are. But I just saw reviews of the netgear AX1800 wifi extender  that got goog review and I think I'm going to go with that.

Comment: For hardware recommendations: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/